# Add several class instances to a 'container' class property object

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I've created two classes, jsCart which represents a shop's cart, and jsProduct which represents a product.

jsCart should have an object as a property to store jsProduct instances.

My question is how to add jsProduct instances to that object property of jsCart.

This is jsCart (relevant bits)

```
class jsCart {
  constructor() {
    this.products = {};
    this.sum = 0;     
  }

  set _products(product) {
    this.products[product.id] = product;
  }

  remove(id) {
    delete this.products[id];
  }

  updateSum() {
    for (var product in this.products) {
      this.sum += this.products[product]['sum'];
    }
  }
}
```

And jsProduct (relevant bits):

```
class jsProduct {
  constructor(id, price, quantity) {
    this.id = id;
    this.price = price;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.sum = this.price * this.quantity;
  }

  set _quantity(n) {
    this.quantity = n;
    this.sum = this.price * this.quantity;
  }
}
```

And my attempt to add a product to the cart:

```
jsCart._products = new jsProduct('bananas',23,1);
```

This does seem to work but when I try to add another product, if I am using chrome's console correctly, it seems as it overwrites the first:

[image]

Is it perhaps that I should use a getter to see the content of .products ? or something about the setter or how I am using it?

Thank you

Comment: So, just to get it out of the way.  Javascript does not have `associative arrays`.  And that's not what you are using here.  You're using a simple object with key value pairs.

Comment: Do not (ab)use that `_products` setter as a method. If you have `remove(id)`, you should also have `add(id)` (or `add(product)`)

Comment: Thanks @Taplar I corrected that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just make a method called addItem, and add the item to the 'cart' instead of doing what you were doing.

```
class jsCart {
  constructor() {
    this.products = {};
    this.sum = 0;     
  }
  //You don't really need this
  //set _products(product) {
  //  this.products[product.id] = product;
  //}

  //This should work
  addProduct(product){
    this.products[product.id] = product;
  }

  remove(id) {
    delete this.products[id];
  }

  updateSum() {
    for (var product in this.products) {
      this.sum += this.products[product]['sum'];
    }
  }
}

cart.addProduct(...);
```

Comment: That solves it, thank you. I wonder why does the setter behave like that tho, could you explain? Thanks

Comment: @Jaume Mal, The only thing that I think would be causing that weird behavior is that it is a setter, not a adder. When setting stuff like that, you were saying "hey _products now is (food)" you were then looking at the _products method in your inspector, not cart.products. It's still generally bad convention to do stuff like that, but that was where your problem was

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should not be giving your class instances the same name as the class itselt. Furthermore, the convention for Javascript class names is writing them in Pascal Casing.

So, in your case, it would be:

```
class JSCart{
   ....
}
```

To create an instance of `JSCart`:

```
let jsCart = new JSCart();
```

In addition, I would consider using a setter in the way you did it bad style because the setter does not **set** the value for `products`, but it **adds** a product to your `products`. A better way would be creating a method to add a new product.

Technically, your solution should work. The only thing that can not work is retrieving your current products with a getter that does not exist (in your case the `jsCart._products`). Instead, you can simpy access the products as a property of your cart.

[Example for creating two products and retrieving the cart's products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJdPC.png)

Also, rethink if you need to store your products in an object. It seems to me that an array would fit your case better.
When using an object in the way you did it, you do not have the possibility to add two products with the same name (e.g. "apple" and "apple") as the second product would overwrite the first one.
Using an object has the advantage of directly accessing a product by it's name. If you do not need this and you simply need to store products that have been added to the user's cart, prefer an array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the additional advice. In this case I'd like to access the products by id and that seems easier if I use an object.